# How to re-use the firestore's db accross the different page in View?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vueuse

I'm creating for the first time a Vue app with VueUse.

In my main.ts, I've this:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  //....
}
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = getFirestore(app)
export const useTodos= createGlobalState(
  () => useFirestore(collection(db, 'todos')),
)
```

So in my views, when I want to use my Todos, it works fine with the useTodos hook, but there is a lot of time where I need to access a very specific document(something like `/collection/key-one/sub-collections/key-two/property` ).

Typically, I would access this:

```
const someDocument = useFirestore(doc(db, 'collection', myKey, 'sub-collections', myKeyTwo))
console.log(someDocument.property)
```

But I don't have access to the `db` field. How can I retrieve it?

Comment: `export const db = getFirestore(app)` and then `import { db } from "../path/to/firebase.js"` should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, and assuming that you are using Firebase V9 or greater,

In your main.ts

```js
export const db = getFirestore(app)
```

In other views:

```js
import { db } from "../path/to/firebase.js"

const someDocumentRef = doc(db, `collection/${id}/sub-collection/${id}`);

const someDocumentSnapshot = await getDoc(someDocumentRef);

const myDoc = someDocument.data();

const myProperty = myDoc.someProperty;
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I'm curious, what part of my example is "previous methods of querying firestore" ?

Comment: I was mistaken. I have edited the solution, while noting that the solution I provided is for V9 Firebase- There may still be people using pre V9 SDK and this solution would not be entirely correct for them.